# access property of new window opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, properties, window.open, cross-site

I have to send some coordonates to another window that opens a map adress by

```
winMap=window.open('${mapServerUrl}','_blank','modal=true');
```

but when I'm trying to acces the propperties of the map window,

```
if (typeof winMap.atlas != 'undefined' && typeof winMap.atlas.map != 'undefined' && winMap.atlas.map.isMapLoaded())
```

.......

the browser gives me `"Error: Permission denied to access property 'atlas'"`.

I know that this case enters to the case of "cross-site scripting" but how can I send the coords to the map windows to show them to the user?

Thanks

Comment: If ${mapServerUrl} does not have the exact same origin as the page that opens it, forget it

Comment: so I have to host the atlas page (map service) under my localhost?

Comment: Browsers won't allow cross-domain access. Perhaps you can pass the coordinates in through the initial URL.